# Single quotes affecting the calculations in Select query

Tags: mysql

```
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM area
WHERE ROUND(SQRT(POWER(('71' - coords_x), 2) +
                 POWER(('97' - coords_y), 2))) <= 17

==> 51

SELECT COUNT(*) FROM area
WHERE ROUND(SQRT(POWER((71 - coords_x), 2) +
                 POWER((97 - coords_y), 2))) <= 17

==> 22
```

coords_x and coords_y are both TINYINT fields containing values in the range [1, 150]. Usually MySQL doesn't care if numbers are quoted or not.. but apparently it does in this case.

The question is just: Why?

Comment: Another question would be: why do you want to treat numbers like strings?

Comment: I can't see a reason for it offhand, but you could try reversing things a bit ... select out the value you're trying to compare in the WHERE clause, and see what the value is in both cases?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

MySQL **always** cares about data types. What happens is that your code relies in automatic type casting and performs math on strings (which can hold a number or not). This can lead to all sort of unpredictable results:

```
SELECT POW('Hello', 'World') -- This returns 1
```

To sum up: you need to learn and use the different data types MySQL offers. Otherwise, your application will never do reliable calculations.

**Update:**

One more hint:

> TINYINT[(M)] [UNSIGNED] [ZEROFILL]
>
> A very small integer. The signed range
>   is -128 to 127. The unsigned range is
>   0 to 255.
>
> URL:
>   http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/numeric-type-overview.html

I hope you are not trying to store `150` in a signed tinyint column.